# Is there a problem with how I am calling the member functions?

Tags: c++

Write a program with a class called Dice in a file called "Dice.h" that has as a member object a vector that simulates the rolling of a single die a hundred times. as well as a member variable called Size which contains the size of the vector.

In the file Dice.cpp, the Dice class should have the following public member functions defined:

a default constructor which sets all of the values of the vector member object to 0.
roll100() which rolls the die 100 times and records that roll in the vector member object.
calculateRolls() which calculates the number of 1 rolls, the number of 2 rolls, the number of 3 rolls, the number of 4 rolls, the number of 5 rolls, and the number of 6 rolls.  The function then displays the number of the respective rolls to the user.
printDice() which displays the contents of the vector to the screen with 10 elements of the vector per line for 10 lines.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaYHG.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6gxj.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzijH.png

```
Main.cpp:

#include <iostream>
#include "Dice.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  Dice roll;
  
  roll.roll100();
  roll.calculateRolls();
  roll.printDice();
 
}

Dice.cpp:

#include "Dice.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

Dice::Dice() {
  vector <int> rolls(SIZE, 0);
}
const int SIZE = 100;
vector <int> rolls(SIZE, 0);
int ones;
int twos;
int threes;
int fours;
int fives;
int sixes;

void roll100() {
  unsigned seed = time(0);
  srand(seed);
  int result;
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    result = (rand() % 6 + 1);
    rolls[i] = result;
  }
}

void calculateRolls()
{
 for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
   if (rolls[i] == 1)
     ones++;
   if (rolls[i] == 2)
     twos++;
   if (rolls[i] == 3)
     threes++;
   if (rolls[i] == 4)
     fours++;
   if (rolls[i] == 5)
     fives++;
   if (rolls[i] == 6)
     sixes++;
 }
    cout<<"Number of 1 rolls "<<ones<<"\n";
    cout<<"Number of 2 rolls "<<twos<<"\n";
    cout<<"Number of 3 rolls "<<threes<<"\n";
    cout<<"Number of 4 rolls "<<fours<<"\n";
    cout<<"Number of 5 rolls "<<fives<<"\n";
    cout<<"Number of 6 rolls "<<sixes<<"\n";  
}

void printDice() {
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    if (i % 9 == 0) 
      cout << endl;
    cout << rolls[i];
  }
} 

Dice.h:

#ifndef DICE_H
#define DICE_H
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Dice {
  private:

  public:
    const int SIZE = 100;
    int ones;
    int twos;
    int threes;
    int fours;
    int fives;
    int sixes;

    Dice();

    void roll100();
    void calculateRolls();
    void printDice();
    
};
#endif
```

Comment: You created free functions in Dice.cpp and not class member functions of your Dice class.

Comment: I tried to help by copying your code into my IDE, but my IDE cannot extract code from your images.  No code posted as text == no help.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I just added the code!

Comment: Don't put `srand(time(0))` in a function that might be called repeatedly. That should be done *exactly* once in `main` before you do anything else, then never done again, unless you really like *every* call to `roll100` within a one-second window producing the same values over and over. Practically, speaking, you should be using C++11's newer `<random>` functionality, because `srand`/`rand` are *terrible* in every way.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dice.cpp needs

```
Dice::calculateRolls(){....}
```

etc

PS. I did not look for any other errors, just your given compile errors.

Comment: Thank you!! it is now compiling, but I am getting                                                            
Number of 1 rolls 13
Number of 2 rolls 4816979
Number of 3 rolls 14
Number of 4 rolls 4218641
Number of 5 rolls 18
Number of 6 rolls 461636515 for the first output portion, which means the 2, 4, and 6 rolls aren't being collected correctly

Comment: You have multiple variables with the same name in different scopes. This problem probably was a result of your first bug of creating free functions.  You never initialized your class members: `ones` , `twos` ... as a result these will have random garbage values.

Comment: Nevermind, i initialized my number variables to 0 and it fixed that issue. Thanks again!

Comment: You should remove the global variables in `Dice.cpp` comment them out first then remove after compiling to make sure none of them are being used anywhere.

Comment: I removed them and it runs fine! So for a rule of thumb, I shouldn't include globals in the cpp file?

Comment: @beansogo typically the cpp file for a class  only contains the code for members of that class. No other data, globals etc

Comment: I would avoid global variables as it can lead to more difficult to debug and understand when you program grows to many source files. However in this case I wanted you to remove them because they were not used and also they may add to confusion since they have the same names of your class member variables.